# XAML 2009 support in VS and blend

Tags: xaml

When can we expect XAML 2009 support in the tools like Expression Blend 4, Visual Studio 2010? Has Microsoft mentioned something somewhere publically? Willl we have to wait for Blend 5 and VS 2012?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Microsoft has mentioned this, from my understanding you can use it in WPF if you use loose Xaml files, but no designer support.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My question was regarding the tooling.